# Add percentage numbers from a cell in PPTX

Tags: python, excel, powerpoint, python-pptx

I'm a novice in Python, and I'm struggling with `pptx rn`.

I have an `xlsx` file and I want to import a single percentage number from a cell in my presentation.

Here is the traceback:

```
line 40, in to_unicode
    raise TypeError("expected unicode string, got %s value %s" % (type(text), text))
TypeError: expected unicode string, got <class 'float'> value 0.29
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
subtitle.text = str(active_sheet['C8'].value)
```

as a start. This should avoid the exception, but might not give you the exact representation you want.

I expect it will give you "0.29", but let's come back to that. The reason you are getting the exception is because you are assigning a numeric (float) value to a property that expects a `str` value. Converting it to string using the built-in `str()` function takes care of that.

To get a percentage representation, try:

```
subtitle.text = "{:.0%}".format(active_sheet['C8'].value)
```

There are other ways of what is called *interpolating* strings from numbers in Python that you can find on search, but this is a good one in this case.